# Angular2+ change in dropdown options array not being detected

Tags: angular

I have two  dropdowns. On the change of the first one, it changes the options value of the second. So when I change the profile, I want a new set of options in my size dropdown.

```
<select (change)="onProfileChanges($event)" [(ngModel)]="config.profile">
    <option *ngFor="let profile of availableProfiles" [value]="profile.Name">
{{profile.Label}}</option>
</select> 

<select (change)="onSizeChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="config.size">
    <option *ngFor="let size of selectedSizes" [ngValue]="size.Name">{{profile.Label}}</option>
</select>

//Component Code

selectedSizes: any[];

onProfileChanges(event: any) {
    this.selectedSizes = this.availableProfiles[event.target.selectedIndex].Sizes;
}
```

The problem is, the value is visibly changed in the dropdown, but it is not updated to config.size it is still the previous value. How do I make sure the value is changed when the options are changed?

Comment: Can you post your component code? And quotes are recommended in your HTML template, like [(ngModel)]="config.size".

Comment: Added quotes...The relevant component code is the function that is setting the selectedSizes, which is declared as selectedSizes: any[]; I don't know what else you would need to know.

Comment: how about config object? is it initiated when loading the component?

Comment: Yes, in ngOnInit, it is retrieved from a REST call.

Comment: you'd better debug it in onSizeChange event. console.log(this.config) to see if it is changed indeed?

Comment: onSizeChange doesn't get called unless I manually change the value.

Comment: onSizeChange() is not  called unless I change the sizes manually.

Comment: whenever the list changes, you need to reset 'config.size'. it cannot be still bound to an value of an old list. is that what you want?

Comment: yes. My assumption is that it would happen automatically because of binding.

Answer (score 0):

You call onProfileChange but the method name to onProfileChanges

Comment: That's just a typo here. The actual method does get called when a profile is selected.

Comment: then you should use ChangeDetectorRef  detectChanges method